# Is there a Shiny input for relative dates?

Tags: r, shiny

I´d like to add to my app something like this:

[image: Relative Date Slicer in Power BI]

Is there an input ready to use or do I have to program it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Relative Date Input in `shiny`

What you can do is use `numericInput` to specify how many days, months, or years you would like to go back.

For example

```
numericInput("relativedate","Select days back",value = 30, min = 1)

data <- reactive(data %>% filter(Date >= max(data$Date) - input$relativedate & Date <= max(data$Date)) %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(count = n(),mean = mean(col1)
```

Similarly, for months and years, you can use `lubridate`. [Read more here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html)

```
library(lubridate)

numericInput("relativedate","Select months back",value = 2, min = 1)

data <- reactive(data %>% filter(Date >= max(data$Date) %m-% months(input$relativedate) & Date <= max(data$Date)) %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(count = n(),mean = mean(col1)

numericInput("relativedate","Select years back",value = 5, min = 1)

data <- reactive(data %>% filter(Date >= max(data$Date) - years(input$relativedate) & Date <= max(data$Date)) %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(count = n(),mean = mean(col1)
```